# The best algorithms to detect continuing decrease pattern on conversion data

Tags: algorithm, math, anomaly-detection

I'm tring to use an algorithm for finding and ranking continuing decreases in my data.
The base condition:

The breakpoint location (blue arrow) is unknown but bigger than x (can be on t= 4 or in t=9 but can't be smaller than t=2 for example )

Part B (after the breakpoint)  has smaller AVG than Part A (before the breakpoint) significantly given the data variance.

The larger the ratio between part A and part B, the higher the score.

Need suggestions for the best practice.

[image]

UPDATE: I spit the X axis to last 2 days and 10 days before those days.
and used SUM((x_last_2_days -x_avg last_10_days)/std_over_all )

So I got the following patterns

Rank 2 - fine
[image]

Rank 3 - controversial
[image]

Rank 6 - bad
[image]

Rank 7 - good
[image]

Rank 8 - bad
[image]

How to ignore the bad pattern or improve the algo.

Comment: Such "jumps" are difficult to detect and in fact often quite subjective. (Why, for instance, don't you consider the downward edge in the right yellow zone ?). Consider the CUSUM method.

Comment: "How to ignore the bad pattern or improve the algo." Please post some data sets to test candidate algorithms.

Comment: There's no "best practice."  There are just tools and heuristics.  The main tool is filtering to remove noise.  A running average is only one kind of filter.  The heuristics are mainly thresholding rules.  The other approach you can try is building a randomized _generator_ of examples along with the intended scores. Then train a neural network to produce the score as output.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are dealing with a noisy [time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series). Your problem as formulated is known [step detection or edge detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_detection). Your approach to solve it is listed in the wiki there (look for sliding window). Because the data is noisy, you do have to employ statistical methods to detect features in the noisy data to differentiate a change in the pattern from pure noise. Concrete implementation would require some analysis and possibly simulations.

In general, analysis of time series and signal processing involves de-trending, de-seasoning, edge detection, so that all that remains is pure white noise. Tools used are [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation), etc.